# How do I make my code not generate new integers when the user gets the answer wrong?

Tags: python, loops, math

What the code below does is that it generates 2 random integers and multiplies them together. After the user has placed an input and gets it corrects, it will automatically generate another pair of random integers.

How could I make it so that when the user input is wrong, it does not generate a number but waits till the user to finally calculate the correct answer and then it generates a new set of integers?

I've been playing around with having a loop within the main loop but it hasn't solved my problem

```
while loop:

new_ints = True

while new_ints:

    random_int_1 = random.randint(2,9)
    random_int_2 = random.randint(2,9)

    answer = random_int_1*random_int_2

    equation = (f"{random_int_1}x{random_int_2} = ? ")
    print(equation)

    user_answer = int(input())

    if answer == user_answer:
        print("correct")
        new_ints = True
        loop = True
    else:
        print("Wrong")
        new_ints = True
        loop = False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the `if` statements you can simply have another while loop to check the guess like this:

```
while int(input()) != answer:
    print('Incorrect. Guess again')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! These 2 lines of code has solved my issue whilst allowing me to delete 9 lines of code and making my code look neater!

Answer (score 1):

Simply add an if condition before the generation of ints:

```
while True:
    if new_ints:
        random_int_1 = random.randint(2,9)
        random_int_2 = random.randint(2,9)
        answer = random_int_1*random_int_2
```

You need to decide which condition will break the loop. Imho, you can eliminate the external loop as well, just keep the `while True` and establish a `break` condition

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `while-else` to solve the problem. The loop will keep repeating if the user's input is not equal to the actual answer, otherwise it will print "correct" and move on to the next question. Below is the complete code after revising.

```py
import random

while True:
    random_int_1 = random.randint(2,9)
    random_int_2 = random.randint(2,9)

    answer = random_int_1*random_int_2

    equation = (f"{random_int_1}x{random_int_2} = ? ")
    print(equation)

    user_answer = ''
    while int(input()) != answer:
        print("Wrong")
    else:
        print("correct")
```

Comment: The `else` here isn't really needed. Since there is no `break` it will always be executed and equivalent to having it outside the loop.